# DB2 and MQ integration

Tags: database, db2, ibm-mq, db2-luw

I'm trying to integrate DB2 and IBM MQ together. My goal is to transfer chosen information from database on one system to database on other system through MQ. I know that there is this Q replication function, but I wanted to use single MQ commands available in DB2. I'm using DB2 Advanced Enterprise Server version 11.1 and MQ version 9 on Windows 7 OS.

I went through the DB2 documentation on IBM knowledge base and found information about MQListener command (db2mqlsn), enable_MQFunctionscommand and so on. Problem is, that I can't see those commands in my DB2 installation folder at all. The db2mqlsn utility is supposed to be located in the DB2PATH\sqllib\bin directory, but for me, it is not. I tried to search the word "mq" through the whole SQLLIB directory with windows search but it didn't found nothing much. There's a screenshot with search results.

[image: Windows Search Results]

Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you very much in advance for any help.
Martist

Comment: I would look at the documentation to see if it is an optional feature that is not installed by default.

Comment: @Roger thanks for your reply! I installed all features during DB2 installation... And the documentation doesn't mention anything specific about installation, just that it is a "built-in" functionality

Comment: The executable is present on my V11.1 server installation in ~$DB2INSTANCE/sqllib/bin .  Verify you have the server product installed, you can also check the contents of the response file created at installation, and check the contents of the installation-log-file to see if there were any mq related messages.

Comment: I checked on a Win7 x64 environment running DB2 V11.1 fixpack2 server and the db2mq*.exe files are absent, so it must be an issue specific to Windows installations, because the executables for db2mqlsn are present on Linux for same version.  Check with IBM.

Comment: @mao thanks for your effort. I also just checked the same version on linux and the files are there, so as you said, it must be an issue specific to Windows.